# Laravel making array from collection in controller file

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, drop-down-menu

here is github gist link :  https://gist.github.com/gupta2205/b33dcf762876e5df34d9

```
//trying to make array out of fetured petitions 
// i guess i am doing something wrong in writing it 
//do i need "foreach" here ? to get individual petition->call_to_action access and set key value in array or how can i do it ? please suggest

   $featureList = array(
    '0' => 'before '.Petition::getFeaturedPetitions()->call_to_action.'petition',
    '1'=>  'before '.Petition::getFeaturedPetitions()->call_to_action.'petition',
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably will have to do something like this:

```
$featureList = array();

foreach(Petition::getFeaturedPetitions() as $petition)
{
    $featureList[$petition->id] = 'before '.$petition->call_to_action.'petition';
}
```